# Stop sentry from sending messages

Tags: python, sentry

In case sentry sends lots of similar messages, is there a way to stop it?

We have a lot of clients and the sentry messages are basically all the same so sentry spams me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about notifications you can disable them per-account or entirely on a project via the integration.

That said if all the messages are the same you should look into why they're not grouping. A common case would be you're using a logging integration and there's a variable in the log message itself.

Comment: There indeed was a log variable in the log message. I have changed it. Fingers crossed I've found all occurrences. :-)

Comment: You can use log formatting a lot of times. For example, in Python:

logging.error("An example error: %s", error, exc_info=True)